# Error in docker run hello-world (Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Docker version: 18.09.3.

Service: landscape.canonical.com

When I create a Docker container using `sudo docker run hello-world`, I got the error as below.

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58:
>   **mounting** \\"proc\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/9a16ab705748c4bb269b96db7391b65ba54786f6e722cb32bf5ede32afb67d72\\"
>   at \\"/**proc**\\" caused \\"**permission denied**\\"\"": unknown.

***Does anyone have an idea of this issue?***

***Is it possible to use Docker containers in landscape.canonical.com?***

The output of `sudo docker info`:

[image]

The output of `sudo systemctl status docker.service`:

[image]

Comment: Would it fail if you try starting it with `sudo`: `sudo docker run ...`? Also check whether you user has `docker` group. Check these post-install steps: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: If they’re getting that error, they’ve gotten past needing to run `sudo docker ...`.

Comment: I do not want to assume, I want to understand the set up and move forward from there :). Since the error is about `permission denied` there's something about permissions.

Comment: I tried to use sudo , but still have the same error.

Comment: Can you add the results after running these commands `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` & `sudo systemctl status docker.service`, and `docker info`? The command `docker run hello-world` is the first step to test docker installation. I am guessing you have installation issues.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I will post images right away

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: I don't use Dockerfile to run hello-word in container

Comment: It looks like the same issue was reported in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645910/docker-rootfs-linux-go-permission-denied-when-mounting-proc Do you want to try the accepted solution there?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue relates to a server image created by landscape.canonical.com. Based on what I know, landscape.canonical.com mainly supports LXD. There is a way to use docker inside LXD environment  However, I not sure it is a good way to use Docker.